# Electron's behavior: A Solution to the Hard Problem of Consciousness?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

In recent years, the hard problem of consciousness has been a subject of intense debate and discussion in the field of philosophy and cognitive science. Many researchers and scholars have proposed various theories and hypotheses to explain the nature of subjective experience and consciousness, but the problem remains unsolved.

However, some have suggested that the behavior of electrons may hold the key to understanding consciousness. According to this perspective, the electron always chooses the easiest path, which is a fundamental part of its existence. This behavior allows the electron to form connections between random things, increasing complexity, and ultimately contributing to the emergence of consciousness.

While this may seem like a far-fetched idea, it is worth exploring further. The behavior of electrons is well-documented and can be observed in many scientific experiments. Additionally, the fact that electricity is a fundamental part of our existence and that we contain electrons further supports this theory.

However, it is important to note that this theory is still in its early stages, and more research is needed to fully understand its implications. While it may not provide a definitive solution to the hard problem of consciousness, it offers a unique perspective and could potentially lead to new insights and discoveries.

In conclusion, the behavior of electrons may hold the key to understanding consciousness, but further research is needed to fully explore this theory's potential. As the study of consciousness continues to evolve, it is essential to keep an open mind and consider all possible explanations and perspectives.

Comment: Without a great deal more explanation, there just doesn't seem to be a connection. I think we are in danger of saying: consciousness is weird and quantum mechanics is weird, so maybe they have something to do with each other. Maybe, but it does seem far fetched, at least at present. Roger Penrose and a few others have suggested a connection between them, but it is considered a fringe view.

Comment: This is a recommendation/opinion, not a question. Suggest to close.

Comment: I don't see the connection.

Comment: What does exactly mean "the electron chooses the easiest path" ? In a transistor, because of the tunnel effect, it can be made so that in the same conditions 50% of the electrons will go through and 50% won't. One would expect, if they take the easiest path, that they all together go through or not.

Comment: This seems to be, does consciousness exist because physics exists, & the trivial answer is yes. An actual hypothesis, is something like say the self-organised criticality model. We need ideas that contribute testable predictions, not vague gestures

Comment: For context, what you seem to be referencing is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle one of the most general principles in physics. And, *electrons* don't make connections, that sounds like newage woo, neurons make connections, in neural networks which learn through reinforcing frequently used paths. Perhaps you could link to a paper or article, because what you have posted is far too general a statement to point to anything meaningful. You haven't referenced any theory, you have just said 'electrons exist'

Comment: Penrose made essentially this conjecture in 1989.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Mind